# the trial of still using sed for parsind data.

Tags: bash, sed

I have a list of data; It exceeds itself in its ridiculousness  - picture the same list - with hundreds of thousands of lines. Then add a really self centered, massively rich and entitled sales trades who wants this information NOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
anyhow - Because the A4 and A4EU are the last in the list I decided at the time to parse the list on these values. I did try and parse it by the unique identifier at the beginning  - the 9 digit number. However - the sed for the unique identifier did not work

```
sed -e s'/\d{9}/\n\d{9}/g /tmp/file
```

this did not work
So I parsed it by the A4's

```
231239987
HUBS
46,772
36,772
GOVSING
47.5080
UBS Sales
MONOHAJO
Market
0.00
06Jul15 08:59:18
XNYS
USD
Stock
A4 
231239966
FB
26,641
26,641
GOVSING
87.4324
UBS Sales
MONOHAJO
Market
0.00
06Jul15 08:58:55
XNAS
USD
Stock  
A4
231238664
CR
4,700
0
SIM
0.0000
UBS Sales
MONOHAJO
Market
0.00
06Jul15 08:53:42
XNYS
USD
Stock
A4EU
231238665
SCLN
211,000
186,795
LCFED
10.8647
UBS Sales
MONOHAJO
Limit
10.80
06Jul15 08:53:42  
XNAS
USD
Stock
A4EU
231237844 
VRA
41,900
33,900
ROYCE
11.2169
UBS Sales
MONOHAJO
Limit
11.25
06Jul15 08:40:25
XNAS  
USD
Stock
A4 
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$
bash-3.2$ cat  /tmp/comeandplaywithus | tr "\n" " "  | sed 's/A4EU/A4\n/g' | sed 's/A4/A4\n/g' > /tmp/danny
```

bash-3.2$

This is actually the desired format of the lines.

```
231239987 HUBS 46,772 36,772 GOVSING 47.5080 UBS Sales MONOHAJO Market 0.00 06Jul15 08:59:18 XNYS USD Stock A4
231239966 FB 26,641 26,641 GOVSING 87.4324 UBS Sales MONOHAJO Market 0.00 06Jul15 08:58:55 XNAS USD  Stock
231238664 CR 4,700 0 SIM 0.0000 UBS Sales MONOHAJO Market 0.00 06Jul15 08:53:42 XNYS USD Stock A4EU
231238665 SCLN 211,000 186,795 LCFED 10.8647 UBS Sales MONOHAJO Limit 10.80 06Jul15 08:53:42 XNAS USD Stock A4EU
231237844 VRA  41,900 33,900 ROYCE 11.2169 UBS Sales MONOHAJO Limit 11.25 06Jul15 08:40:25 XNAS USD Stock A4
```

would there have been a way to take parse by the A4's in once sed statement. Parsing by the A4's did lead to some silliness because look at line 2  - it does not end in either A$ or A4EU. So there are thousands of lines that this did not work on. Anyhow -- I tried something like this :

```
cat  /tmp/comeandplaywithus | tr "\n" " "  | sed 's/A4[EU]?/A4\n/g > /tmp/danny
```

Answer (score 2):

other sed

loading the whole in memory

```
sed '1h;1!H;$!d
     x;s/\n/ /g;s/\(A4\(EU\)\{0,1\}\)[[:blank:]]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{9\}\)/\1\
\3/g' YourFile
```

flow version (usefull with `-u`)

```
sed ':cycle
     N
     /\nA4\(EU\)\{0,1\}/ !b cycle
     s/\n/ /g' YourFile
```

An awk

```
awk '/A4(EU){0,1}/ {print Record $0; Record="";next}
     {Record = Record " " $0}' YourFile
```

some minor correction (but that change everything cfr comment of @User112638726)

Comment: None of these will work. **First one**, why are you matching numbers before the A4 and you remove all newlines so its just one long line. **Second one** match A4 at the start of the line, but it won't ever be at the start because you have tons of lines before it in the pattern space. **Third one** you need to set record before you print or you lose A4/A4EU

Comment: sorry a bit in a hurry due to BAU, value are reversed in first sed, a  start of line instead of new line in second and forget to print current record also in awk. correction done thanks to @User112638726

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
sed -E -n '/[0-9]{9}/{ h; b; }; H; /^A4(EU)?$/{ x; s/\n/ /g; p; }'
```

Comment: @capser If you're looking for a concise tutorial, the original [article](http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/tutorials/sed_mcmahon.txt) is a good place to start.  Still the best text on `sed` to this day, IMHO.

Comment: @capser:  there are two buffers used by `sed`.  By default you use the *pattern space*, but there is also the *hold space* which is used here.  Moving text between the two always reminds me of writing assembler.  Maybe it is time for you to move on to something like Perl or Python?